# Erro: (The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://.. url timed out after 60 seconds) ao executar teste

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testes

Ao tentar executar os testes no Internet Explorer é apresentado o seguinte erro (The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52875/session/8d661993-7a95-49fb-9c95-e7fe231e9394/url timed out after 60 seconds). A página do teste abre mas após um tempo o erro é exibido. Já tentei aumentar o tempo de espera e não resolveu. Coloco em observação que no Chrome funcionou como devido.  Encontrei perguntas antigas relacionadas mas as soluções não me ajudaram. Hoje há algo definitivo para correção do problema? Abaixo exemplo do código.

```
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;
    IWebDriver driver = new 
    InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Users\gusta\source\repos\sorteio\sorteio\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"/, options);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/?cc=br");

    IWebElement webElement = wait.Until(e => 
    e.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/header/div/div/a[1]/span[2]")));
    webElement.Click();
```

Comment: olá @Gustavo, para usar o IEDriverServer nas versões mais novas do IE (acredito que esteja usando IE versão 10 ou +), tem algumas configurações que precisa fazer na máquina onde vai rodar o teste veja esse link: [https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

Comment: Para o IE 11 única , você precisará definir uma entrada de registro no computador de destino para que o motorista pode manter uma conexão com a instância do Internet Explorer que ele cria. Para instalações do Windows de 64 bits, a chave é HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Observe que a FEATURE_BFCACHEsubchave pode ou não estar presente e deve ser criada se não estiver presente. Importante: Dentro dessa chave, crie um valor DWORD nomeado iexplore.exe com o valor 0. Isso me ajudou obrigado.